# Track Delegators for a particular Validator

Tags: rpc, cli

I'm currently looking for a way to track delegator activity for any particular validator. I'd like to run this locally and use some form of API/RPC call to access the data. Basically, I don't necessarily want to rely on going to SolanaBeach every time and manually searching for delegator information. Other protocols have this functionality where you can make a query at the latest block height and check delegator information for a particular validator.

Comment: I found a command in the CLI: https://docs.solana.com/cli/usage#solana-stakes. Seems to be returning delegate information for a provided validator pubkey.

Comment: please post solutions as answers, not comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:  [docs.solana.com/cli/usage#solana-stakes](https://%20docs.solana.com/cli/usage#solana-stakes)

Call the Solana CLI command to access the staking information for delegators.

Answer (score 2):

```
//stake account is owned by the stake program which runs the complex transactions requried to facilitate staking.
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey } = require("@solana/web3.js");
const getDelegators = async () => {
  // establish the connection with solana
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "processed");
  // we have to interact with StakeProgram manually
  // https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs
  const STAKE_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(
    "Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111"
  );
  const VALIDATOR_PUB_KEY = "******************************";
  // STAKE ACCounts are owned by the stake program
  const accounts = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(STAKE_PROGRAM_ID, {
    filters: [
      { dataSize: 200 },
      {
        // "memory comparison" filter, allows us to compare data at any field stored on our account. Specifically, we can query only for accounts that match a particular set of bytes at a particular position.
        memcmp: {
          //offset: number - Number of bytes into account data to begin returning
          offset: 124,
          bytes: VALIDATOR_PUB_KEY,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
  console.log("DELEGATORS ARRAY ", accounts);
};
```

Comment: Isn't your VALIDATOR_PUB_KEY larger than 128 bytes and so you hit this error? https://docs.rs/solana-core/1.5.14/src/solana_core/rpc.rs.html#1590